# Binary Search Function

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary, binary-search

Good evening. I am trying to get back in to programming and have decided to do some practice coding on my own time. I'm currently trying to implement a binary search but there appears to be a continuous loop in my code. Could someone give me a hint as to what is going on?

```
def binChop(key, ordered_set):

    found = False
    newSet = ordered_set

    while found != True or newSet > 0:
        midpoint = int(len(newSet)/2)
        if key < newSet[midpoint]:
            found = False
            newSet = newSet[:midpoint]
        elif key > newSet[midpoint]:
            found = False
            newSet = newSet[midpoint:]
        elif key==newSet[midpoint]:
            found = True
    return found
```

Comment: There's no valid exit condition if the set is reduced to a single element (or zero elements) and the search key is not found. (*Edit*: unless `newSet > 0` actually checks whether `len(newSet) > 0`; what is the type of `ordered_set`?)

Comment: That was an error from the number of different edits I've done. Thanks for catching it but it still hits an endless loop somewhere :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the condition for the while loop. You have an 'or' rather than an 'and' - this means that even if you find your result, the newSet>0 condition will be satisfied.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Unfortunately I can't get it to return False if a number isn't in the set. Just loops. That should narrow it down for me though. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect "newSet > 0" is always true. If it was a standard python set, you would get an error:

```
>>> b=set()
>>> b
set([])
>>> b > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only compare to a set
```

But since you don't, I guess it's a list or tuple:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a > 0
True
>>> b=()
>>> b > 0
True
```

Which both don't do what you expect (checking for length).

In general, add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to the code and step through it to find a bug.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the heads up. That will come in handy

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues and some that can be improved :

- You need the left and right boundary index to correctly perform binary search when the element is not in the ordered list. See the correct algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). You get out of the while loop when you either find your key or the left boundary is on the right of the right boundary or vice versa (`max_point < min_point`).
- You don't need the `newSet`. You can always use an index into the sorted list. So the mid_point is just an index, so do `min_point` (the left boundary) and `max_point` (the right boundary).
- A binary search usually returns the index of key as return. If not found, return `-1`.

My python code is shown as below:

```
def binChop(key, ordered_list):

    min_point, max_point = 0, len(ordered_list)-1

    while min_point <= max_point:
        mid_point = (min_point+max_point)/2

        if ordered_list[mid_point] < key:
            min_point += 1
        elif ordered_list[mid_point] > key:
            max_point -= 1
        else:
            return mid_point
    return -1

test_cases = [[], [5], [4,5], [5,6], [1,5,6], [1], [1,4], [1,6,15]]
for ordered_list in test_cases:
    print "%-10s %5s" % (ordered_list, binChop(5, ordered_list))
```

---

```
Outputs:
list       index of 5
[]            -1
[5]            0
[4, 5]         1
[5, 6]         0
[1, 5, 6]      1
[1]           -1
[1, 4]        -1
[1, 6, 15]    -1
```